# Installing Zeppelin and spark on vmware

Tags: vmware, apache-zeppelin

I installed zeppelin and spark on VMware work station (centos7).

- I installed java
- Adding java home
- Adding spark home to zeppelin

I dont want to start zeppelin from localhost adress but from the ip adresse of VMware.

Example :

`192.168.198.32:8080` from the host, but it's unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot time of search i found the solution so i shared with you :

Change NAT Settings

- Select Applications > System Tools > Virtual Network Editor.
- The menu path might be different for your version of Linux. You can
  also start the network editor from the command line by using the
  vmware-netcfg command.
- Select the NAT network, and click NAT Settings.
- ADD the adresse of host and save.